# Serialize only one element in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have form (e.g. form1) with multiple input elements (for id, name, phone,..) and the below jquery ajax call serializes the complete form to object and converts it to string object in the line data:JSON.stringify(jsObj)

```
var jsObj = $form1.serializeObject();
$.ajax(){
type:"POST",
url:"/user/jqXHRUser",
data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),
dataType: "json",
contentType:"application/json",
success:function(data){
console.log("success");
},
error:function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
console.log("failure");
}
}
```

How can i get the specific input element (e.g. name), serialize it and then convert it to string object?

Comment: I figured it out just now, get the input element like                      var userId = $('input[name=userId]').val();
var user = {"userId": userId};                                                          and in ajax call, use "user" variable

Comment: Yeah, basically. jQuery (which is what you just used) is incredibly useful for grabbing only the pieces of data that you want in a page based on attributes that you assigned to the data previously. If you haven't already I would highly recommend watching a jQuery tutorial. It's a standard tool in any web developer's toolbox.

Comment: Thanks! will check the tutorial